# return data and count as json toghether

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, sql-server-2016

Consider following table:

```
[Id: 1, Name: "A1"], [Id: 2, Name: "A2"], ... [Id: 100, Name: "A100"]
```

I need data with Id <= 50, with paging. So I write

```
select * 
from data 
where Id <= 50 order by Id 0 rows fetch next 10 rows only
```

And then I execute another query

```
select count(1) 
from data 
where Id <= 50
```

Then I return json like this to client

```
{
   count:50,
   values:[{Id:1, Name:'A1'}, ..., {Id:10,Name:'A10'}]
}
```

How can I create that json in SQL Server 2016 using **1** select and roundtrip to db only?

Comment: You don't need a query for your page variable. Just project a calculated field onto the result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
select (select count(1) from data where Id <= 50) as total,
(select * from data where Id <= 50 order by Id 0 rows fetch next 10 rows only FOR JSON PATH) as values
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

It results into

```
{
    count:50,
    values:[{Id:1, Name:'A1'}, ..., {Id:10,Name:'A10'}]
}
```

Comment: Limit is not standard Sql Server syntax. You don't get an error?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The complete (but complex) answer is ```select * from (select '#metadata/cities' as '@odata.context', 
     (select count_big(1) from bit.Cities where Name like '%1%') as '@odata.count',
     (select * from bit.Cities where Name like '%1%' order by Id asc offset 0 rows fetch next 10 rows only for json path) as 'value') as ODataResult
for json auto, without_array_wrapper```

Comment: Which results into ```{"@odata.context":"#metadata\/cities","@odata.count":3000,"value":[{"Id":"95ADC4B9-120E-4BDB-ABB7-000179B1F40B","Name":"City14792","ProvinceId":"2F013E2C-913E-40D4-9A2A-4F7905B5D440"},...,{"Id":"F239515A-2C4B-41BA-9503-00274638BDC9","Name":"City11372","ProvinceId":"2F013E2C-913E-40D4-9A2A-4F7905B5D440"}]}``` As you can see, there is a @odata.context column name there. json "path" creates nested object for dot .
So I wrapped first result in derived table named "ODataResult" then I used for json "auto" which does not change the result like that. Works like a charm! (-:

Comment: bit.cities table script: ```CREATE TABLE [bit].[Cities](
 [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [ProvinceId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL)```

Answer (score 0):

This works...is it what you are after is unclear.

```
DECLARE @X TABLE(Id INT)
INSERT  @X SELECT 1
INSERT  @X SELECT 2
INSERT  @X SELECT 3

SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    @X 
    INNER JOIN(SELECT YourCount=COUNT(*) FROM @X)AS X ON 1=1
```

And here is a more efficient way when the filter clause is known.

```
DECLARE @X TABLE(Id INT)
INSERT  @X SELECT 1
INSERT  @X SELECT 2
INSERT  @X SELECT 3


DECLARE @MyFilterCount INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @X WHERE 1=1)

SELECT  
    MyCount=@MyFilterCount
    ,* 
FROM 
    @X
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to check that, then I can notify you here.

Comment: It returns this ```[{"MyCount":3,"Id":1},{"MyCount":3,"Id":2},{"MyCount":3,"Id":3}]``` Which is obviously different from ```{"MyCount":3, data: [{"Id":1},{"Id":2},{"Id":3}]}```

Comment: I added the answer.